# MongoDB + Java + Search to fetch field or column names only after searching a string in a document using either full text or regular search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I am am in need of a solution quickly for the following:

Assuming that I have n numbere of documents in collection XYZ similar to below:

XYZ{
NAME: Test
AGE: 33
ADDRESS: ASDF
EDUCATION: BSC
}

If I want to search for a string say: "BSC"
I want the api to search for the string "BSC", and after successful search, it has to return me only the column name( or field name) of the document XYZ: "EDUCATION"

Any quick help for the solution of the above problem would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the value of your `XYZ` field a long string ("NAME: Test AGE: 33 ADDRESS: ASDF EDUCATION: BSC") or are those actually meant to be separate fields?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not allow you full text search, Sorry, I am not able to comment this one, Don't have appropriate points.